# Statistical Thermodynamics question. Microstate and Macrostate

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

Here is the question:

[image]

I'm confused about probability of macrostate. What is its formula and its definition?

I need formula and physical explanation so i can write my code.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microstate_(statistical_mechanics)

Comment: How many microstates can exist to give you same same single macrostate is the difference between the two terms.  If a train carriage has 50 seats, and they are all occupied (the macrostate), in how many different ways can the passengers arrange themselves (i.e. the large number of microstates) in order to fill up the train carriage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be familiar with [Statistical Mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_mechanics) and the model of the [Einstein solid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_solid)

In extremely short, Statistical Mechanics describes a system of many components with probabilities of the components being in different configurations. The equations you want depend on what the system is and what the components are. A micro-state is a specific configuration of the system, and a macro-state is how that configuration looks like at a global scale. For example, if the system is an [Ideal gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas), the system is a gas contained in a certain volume V and with a total energy E, and the components are tiny hard balls travelling freely inside that volume and with different velocities. The properties E and V describe the macro-state. But a micro-state is any configuration of the balls, where they are in different positions and with different velocities. The thing is that many of these configurations will result in the same global properties of the macro-state E and V.

In that case is clear how to represent the probability of the micros-state: $1/N_{tot}$ where $N_{tot}$ the number of total micro-states (configurations) of the system.

In the [Einstein solid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_solid) the system is a bunch of atoms which can have discrete amounts of energy. Then the microstates are the different ways in which the total energy of the system can be distributed into discrete amounts over the different atoms.

Beyond this short explanation, you need to specify better the system and components in order to get specific equations. You can get inspiration from the wikipedia webpages linked above.